# xp stuck in sleep mode

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I recently uninstalled a wireless printer and it asked me to restart the xp desktop machine, which I did. However, when it restarts it says 'entering sleep mode' and just recycles itself and keeps rebooting into this sleep mode. I tried going into safe mode, but just restarts in sleep mode. Same with last known configuration. Also changed the BIOS to default. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this? Thanks

Comment: Is it the machine or the monitor that's asleep?  If the monitor isn't getting any signal it would go to sleep right away.  Either way is a problem but different.

Comment: it is the machine I think. The monitor shows post screen then the pc says entering sleep mode and restarts. thanks

Comment: Try this http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/268696-45-stuck-sleep-mode ... if it works I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: problem is, I can't go into safe mode or any other mode. just sleep mode. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the Windows XP CD into your CD/DVD drive.
Restart your computer.
It should now be booting off your Windows XP disc.  *(check your BIOS, if not)*

While it is booting off the disk you should get a prompt to *Press R to enter recovery Console*. Press <kbd>R</kbd>.

Press **1** to log onto Windows then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will need the administrative password to get into to command prompt. If the administrator password was blank press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

from the command prompt:

```
ATTRIB -R -S -H hiberfil.sys
DEL hiberfil.sys
```

now the hibernation file is gone, it should boot normally.
more info about recovery mode at [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314058)

Comment: Thank you Sean. Not back at pc till Thursday. Shall report back. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Sean. Worked like a charm. Because I am new user, I cannot rep up. So, thank you.

Comment: accept the answer, that will give me *(and you)* rep